# How to connect to a web service that has no metadata endpoint?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a customer who hosts a WCF web service having no "metadata endpoint". We are writing a C# .Net3.5 client application (a Windows Forms application, by the way) that is to retrieve data from this web service.

Using Visual Studio to add a service reference to my project, or using the WCFTestClient tool to connect, both fail to respond - apparently because they rely on that metadata endpoint to 'discover' what the web service offers. However the customer is not prepared to add a metadata endpoint.

How (in a C# class library in VS2008 ) do I connect to and retrieve data from such a web service?

Comment: They could provide you with a wsdl which should describe the available methods, parameters and return types. You can then use this to create your web reference I think. What have they told you about the web service?

Comment: They've given me a URL  (IP:port) to use. That's it.

Comment: Can anyone guide me on how to create "my own web reference" programmatically? That's the hub my my question. Visual Studio won't do this unless there is a metadata endpoint.

Comment: They'll need to provide you with some specification on how the web service works. I don't think it's possible to interrogate a web service to get its definition unless the metadata endpoint is available. The following article describes how to do the process manually but as I said above you need to know the web methods, what their parameters are and what their return types are. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/accessing-wcf-service-without-creating-proxy/

Comment: If it works, that document looks just the job. I already have a specification of the method calls (URLs) - it was the basic plumbing I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it as a proxy.
Here's the [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786601/Ways-to-generate-proxy-for-WCF-Service)

Comment: it says...Windows Communication Foundation supports following three ways to generate proxy for a WCF Service.

    Adding Service Reference - which is what I was trying to do.

Comment: All of the approaches defined in your tutorial expect a metadata endpoint to be available, otherwise they don't work. Which brings me back to the question - how do I connect to a web service if I know the URL but it doesn't have a metadata endpoint?

Comment: The answer was - go back to basics. In the end I just added XML to an HttpWebRequest object, and used XPath to extract what I needed in the way of a reply from the HttpWebResponse object that I received back. Came to 3 lines of code in the end. What are all these complicated 'WCF' libraries for?